# Where can I find .cdf files for Affymetrix ChIP-chip data analysis?

Tags: r, microarray

I am analysing microarray ChIP data generated several years ago. I want to use the *affy* package for R. However, in order to load the CEL files and proceed with the analysis, I need the pombe annotation file which comes under the name of **Sp20b_M_v04.cdf**. I have looked everywhere for this file but I am unable to locate it. Is anyone in possession of this file or know where I can download it from?

Comment: Welcome to Bioinformatics.StackExchange @Min! Could you let us know where the instructions indicate that you need the **Sp20b_M_v04.cdf** file? Is this from a colleague's lab notebook, or from the *affy* package's documentation, or somewhere else? This info will be helpful in troublehshooting.

Comment: Hi Min, completely agree with @DanielStandage. You need to [edit] your question and add lot more details, otherwise, it's really hard to help.

Comment: @KamilSJaron I converted your answer to a comment since it wasn't really providing a full answer to the question.

Comment: @terdon I was about to delete it because it was the CEL file I linked, not cdf. ^^

Comment: @min I found the corresponding [ncbi geo page](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM758780). it seems that the file you are referring to isn't uploaded. You must contact authors I believe.

Comment: Crossposted with [biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/367285/)?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's in GEO here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GPL10187

There is apparently a zipped copy linked at the bottom in the supplementary files.

When people upload a study based on an array, there is a corresponding 'platform' record where the array details should be deposited.

Edit: you will probably need to gunzip the file first, to get it into CDF format.